# Gradle sync failed: setup project failed: java.io.EOFException

Tags: java, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, runtime-error

I add a PrefManager file in my project to check first time login in app.After that I start sync gradle.It show me Gradle sync failed: setup project failed: java.io.EOFException error

```java
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "comviewappisome.google.sites.watchandearn"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(':luckyWheel')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'

}
```

Comment: Add `build.gradle` and Exception Stacktrace for better context

Comment: Hey Look at it i have add! @AymanArif

Comment: Stracktrace of the exception as well

Comment: @Ayman Arif issue is fix but new issue Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: Add stacktrace please